# Is the Batman armoury a homage to 1989's classic Batman film?

Tags: reference, dc-extended-universe, batman-1989, justice-league

In *Justice League*, we see Batman has an armory ancient weapons and armour:

[image]

But it reminded me about the 1989's classic Batman film, where Batman had something similar:

[image]

Which I covered in my old question: [What was Bruce Wayne's obsession with unusual looking statues?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60101/what-was-bruce-waynes-obsession-with-unusual-looking-statues).

But here my question is, is this a homage or reference to 1989's Batman in 
Justice league film?

Comment: I can't really see it as an homage, but I could be wrong. I just take this to be sort of trope-y as in, rich eccentric guy collects various armor/weapons/etc.

Comment: I've seen an easter eggs video on youtube that seems to think it was indeed an easter egg.

Answer (score 1):

I do remember this from 1989's movie and as pointed out [in an answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/60103/21081) to your previous question itself, those armours are special armour collected from various cultures, which make Batman look intimidating.

It(the armours and ancient weapons) might be part of Batman's research or probably Bruce's hobby. Or it maybe purely for the gothic look.

The movie was filled with [numerous](https://screenrant.com/justice-league-movie-easter-eggs-references/8/?view=lista) [Easter eggs](https://www.cbr.com/justice-league-easter-eggs/) and [homages](http://comicbook.com/dc/2017/09/17/justice-league-flash-superman-the-movie/). So, it's highly likely that come up with this particular ambiance inside the plane.

---

[Danny Elfman uses](http://www.wearemoviegeeks.com/2017/10/danny-elfmans-score-justice-league-set-drop-november-10/) the same score for Justice League.

Comment: Yeah exploding penguins